# How to efficiently locally store instances of an object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am kind of a beginner in Java. I have this college project where we are asked to build a train booking system (desktop). As part of the app, the admin can add and edit new routes. I want to store those instances of different routes somewhere, but how? I want to be able to add as many as I want, but lists and arrays require for a size to be determined. **How can I store indefinite instances of an object efficiently?** This is the data I want to store for each instance:

```
int routeId;
String deptPoint;
String destPoint;
String transpMode;
int vehicleId;
```

Note: we must use Java data types, no DBs allowed.

Some help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: What's wrong with using a `List`? They have no fixed size, unlike arrays.

Comment: 'How can I store indefinite instances of an object efficiently' -> you can't. There will always be a limit.

Comment: @Stultuske there will be space etc limitations, but I would think OP is referring to java code not limiting the amount of objects stored

Comment: Hey guys! If possible I would like to make it able to persist, if not, I would set a limit. I have being doing some research and I found that I could do that with ArrayList, could that work?

Comment: A naive approach would be to store them in text files, maybe in JSON or XML format. Even some DBs do so, but if you create the storage mechanism yourself, you won't be using a database ;-)

Comment: ^ why not read and write to a file? you can read the file into a list or arraylist at the start of the code, then as admin adds and edits the list/arraylist, overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1):

> but lists and arrays require for a size to be determined.

Incorrect. Arrays have a set size, but not lists. A `List` implementation (if mutable) supports automatic dynamic resizing, up to a limit of two billion items or running out of memory.

Define your class. Here we use the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature in Java
16+ for brevity. But if you need mutable objects, declare a conventional class instead.

```
record Route( int routeId, String deptPoint, String destPoint, String transpMode, int vehicleId ) {}
```

Declare a list to hold objects of that class.

```
List< Route > routes = new ArrayList<> () ;
```

Instantiate `Route` objects, and collect.

```
routes.add( new Route( … ) ) ;
```

Comment: Note that for a college project, Java 16 is probably unavailable, and it's likely the instructor has never heard of Java records.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- - I agree with you that *for a college project, Java 16 is probably unavailable, and it's likely the instructor has never heard of Java records* but we should keep in mind that the answers posted on SO should be useful for the future visitors of the page as well. Today, Java 16 may not be a common thing but when someone lands on this page after a couple of years, it will be a useful answer to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Java lists are not requiring predetermined size, they will change as you add elements and remove them, so they're perfectly fine to store Java objects. Thing you didn't mention is do you need to persist it or not, if you don't need to then you can just do that. If you need to, you'll need database or store it to the file on your machine.

Comment: by saying they're not allowed to use DB's, I think we can assume he mentioned there is no persistence involved

Comment: @Stultuske I'm not sure you can assume that, they can perfectly well require persisting on disk

Comment: @Filip it's a college project. Can you imagine a college saying "you have to persist it, but aren't allowed to use a DB?" especially to people who don't know how?

Comment: Yes I can, there is other options that don't include databases. Not sure what is the point of this comments. Edit: The guy just said that he would like to persist them.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an object that have this fields and put it in a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
public class Route {
  int routeId;
  String deptPoint;
  String destPoint;
  String transpMode;
  int vehicleId;
}
```

As [deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712135/dehaar) suggested, one option would be to store your values in a text file with JSON format. You could use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert to/from JSON really easy. You then only have to implement the mechanism to store this JSON in a local file following [this](https://crunchify.com/how-to-write-json-object-to-file-in-java/) example.